# Correct term for having lost (not cut) one's hair

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is *bald* more correct than *hairless* when referring to someone who has lost their hair? Dictionary.com states that [*bald*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bald?s=t) means

> 1. having little or no hair on the scalp

and that [*hairless*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hairless?s=t) means

> 1. without hair, bald

Both terms imply that a person has lost their hair or has just cut it.

Is there an unambiguous term that specifically means having lost one's hair in the sense that it will not grow anymore?

Comment: I prefer to say that I am "adopting the Jason Statham look". Got the hairline, now I just gotta work on becoming younger, taller, better looking, and a whole lot tougher.... :P

Comment: In general, *bald* implies that nature has conspired to produce that condition, and some other term or contextual clue would be provided if the condition was the result of intentional effort.  Eg, "his clean-shaven head glowed in the moonlight."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are quite correct that simply describing someone simply as **bald** is ambiguous: it could mean that they can no longer grow hair, or that they have cut off all their hair.

To disambiguate:

**Gone bald** describes someone who has lost the ability to grow hair.

(Closely related, **balding** or **going bald** describes someone who is in the process of losing their ability to grow hair; either their hair is thinly distributed, or they have a (presumably small, but definitely increasing in size) bald patch.)

**Shaved** describes someone who has cut off their hair.  (You'll generally want to specify what part of them has been shaved; saying "John has shaved" is not the same as saying "John has shaved his head".)

Comment: Thanks, would shave one's head be similar to trimming one's head?

Comment: No, because you never "trim your head"; the object of "trim" is the thing that is actually being cut, so "trimming your head" would involve removing part of your actual head (i.e. some skin and bone), not the hair.  You would only trim your hair or your nails.  "Shaving" normally means "removing the hair attached to X", so "shaving your head" or "shaving your armpits" or "shaving your legs" are all okay; in the absence of an explicit object, shaving your chin / cheeks / neck is assumed (for men).

Comment: Isn't it politically incorrect to describe someone as *bald* - a bit like calling them *fat*, or *crippled*? I have heard the term *follicularly challenged*!

Comment: Something that might not be immediately obvious to someone unfamiliar with English (and maybe to some English speakers who haven't really thought about it much): gone is just a tense of go. Any appropriate tense of go works there (go bald, went bald, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

A reputable medical website http://webmd.com describes the condition ***alopecia*** as the medical term for ***baldness***.

Notwithstanding a variety of treatments, cosmetics and quackery, the condition is more or less permanent.

***Hairless***, on the other hand, could be the result of a mechanical, not a bioogical process, and can usually be remedied by time and follicular activity.

Comment: You can mention *alopecia totalis* (the loss of all head hair) also.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I think that "hairless" is also too ambiguous.  It could mean that it never had hair to begin with.

I'd go with "gone bald."  If you just say "bald"  it could be temporary, but "gone bald" has a strong implication that it's more or less permanent.

Answer (score 0):

"Hairless" is also ambiguous because it does not refer specifically to head hair. It could refer to a chest that appears hairless, and that would be a more common usage.

A more obscure word meaning the same as hairless is [*glabrous*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/glabrous).

> glabrous gla·brous (glā'brəs)
>   adj.
>   Having no hairs or projections, especially on body parts that normally have hair; smooth.

If the person in question still has some hair, you could go with [*balding*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/balding), which strongly implies a natural decline in hair, as with age.

Comment: I love the word! Yet like *hairless*, it doesn't specify the permanent nature of the condition. I can become *glabrous*  with the aid of some gel and a blade, but such hair as I still own will grow back...shortly.

Comment: This is the better answer. *Hairless* generally suggests no hair anywhere. *Bald* typically refers to head hair (and not to beard or mustache).